# Bound c++ value not updating in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I read from an .ini file into an integer in c++, which is then utilised in QML through binding. In runtime, the value in the .ini file can be changed, which causes the c++ integer to also be changed. I'm finding that although the integer does indeed change in c++ (verified through qDebug()), the bound value in QML doesn't change, despite emitting the required changed() signal. Excerpts of my application structure are shown below:

main.cpp:

```
//Establish the QQmlApplication engine, set context properties for the two c++ files and load the QML file.

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("MainCpp"), new MainCpp());
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("Config"), new Config());
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

maincpp.h:

```
public:
    explicit MainCpp(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_PROPERTY(int someValue READ someValue NOTIFY someValueChanged)
    int someValue(){return m_someValue;}

signals:
    void someValueChanged();

private:
    int    m_someValue;
```

config.h:

```
public:
    explicit Config(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_PROPERTY(int someOtherValue READ someOtherValue NOTIFY someOtheralueChanged)
    int someOtherValue(){return m_someOtherValue;}

signals:
    void someOtherValueChanged();

public:
    void loadSettings();

public:
    int      m_someOtherValue;
    QString  m_File;
```

config.cpp:

```
Config::Config(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_File = "/some/path/to/settings/file/config.ini";
    loadSettings();
}

void Config::loadSettings()
{
    QSettings settings(m_File, QSettings::IniFormat);
    settings.beginGroup("GROUP_NAME");
    m_someOtherValue = settings.value("someOtherValueConfig", "").toInt();
    settings.endGroup();
}
```

maincpp.cpp:

```
MainCpp::MainCpp(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
{
    Config configPointer;
    m_someValue = configPointer.someOtherValue();
    emit someValueChanged();
}
```

main.qml:

```
Window {
    width: 800
    height: 480

    Text {
        id: someText
        text: Config.someOtherValue //This does NOT update on changes to m_someOtherValue on the c++ side
        //text: MainCpp.someValue //This DOES update on change to m_someValue on the c++ side
    }
}
```

The following code is called within maincpp.cpp to update the .ini file:

```
void MainCpp::update(int var)
{
    Config configPointer;

    QSettings settings("/some/path/to/settings/file/config.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
    settings.setValue("GROUP_NAME/someOtherValueConfig", var);
    configPointer.m_someOtherValue = var;
    m_someValue = configPointer.someOtherValue;
    emit configPointer.someOtherValueChanged();
    emit someValueChanged();
}
```

I've added 'emit someOtherValueChanged()' signals to no avail. As mentioned earlier, I know m_someOtherValue has changed, as I use query it with qDebug(). If m_someValue changes, why doesn't QML observe the change in m_someOtherValue?

Comment: You say: *the value in the .ini file can be changed*, and I ask you how is it changed?

Comment: Change `someVOtheralueChanged` to `someOtheralueChanged`, typo.

Comment: I manually modify the .ini and I do not see any of the 2 values changing, explain yourself better.

Comment: It is changed programmatically on input from the user. I have validated that this function works as intended, both by qDebug() and by viewing the .ini file during runtime.

Comment: Then add that, we need a [mcve], and if you do not place it, it does not reproduce your error.

Comment: Do you change Config.someOtherValue or MainCpp.someValue or what variable do you change?

Comment: Updated per your comments. The integer 'var' is sent to update() from a QSlider value change in QML.

Comment: See my answer. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is caused because you have 3 Config objects:

1. main.cpp

---

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("Config"), new Config());
```

2. MainCpp constructor:

---

```
MainCpp::MainCpp(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
{
    Config configPointer; 
    [...]
```

3. update method:

---

```
void MainCpp::update(int var)
{
    Config configPointer;
```

That is to say if changes some of them does not change the other objects since they are different.

A possible solution is to make Config a Singleton, so all the objects will be the same throughout the application.

**config.h**

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSettings>

class Config : public QObject
{
    static Config* instance;
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int someOtherValue READ someOtherValue NOTIFY someOtherValueChanged)
    explicit Config(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public:
    static Config *getInstance();
    int someOtherValue(){return m_someOtherValue;}
    [...]

};

#endif // CONFIG_H
```

**config.cpp**

```
#include "config.h"

Config* Config::instance = 0;

Config::Config(QObject *parent):QObject(parent){
    m_File = "/some/path/to/settings/file/config.ini";
    loadSettings();
}

Config *Config::getInstance(){
    if (instance == 0)
        instance = new Config;
    return instance;
}

void Config::loadSettings(){
    [...]
}
```

The object is then accessed through getInstance ():

**maincpp.cpp**

```
#include "maincpp.h"

MainCpp::MainCpp(QObject *parent):QObject(parent){
    Config *configPointer = Config::getInstance();
    m_someValue = configPointer->someOtherValue();
    emit someValueChanged();
}

void MainCpp::update(int var)
{
    Config *configPointer = Config::getInstance();
    QSettings settings("/some/path/to/settings/file/config.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
    settings.setValue("GROUP_NAME/someOtherValueConfig", var);
    configPointer->m_someOtherValue = var;
    m_someValue = configPointer->someOtherValue();
    emit configPointer->someOtherValueChanged();
    emit someValueChanged();
}
```

To use it in QML you must register with the help of `qmlRegisterSingletonType()`:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "maincpp.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

static QObject *singletonTypeProvider(QQmlEngine *, QJSEngine *)
{
    return Config::getInstance();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterSingletonType<Config>("Config", 1, 0, "Config", singletonTypeProvider);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("MainCpp"), new MainCpp());
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

In the qml you must import the module and use the object:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

import Config 1.0

Window {
    width: 800
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ColumnLayout{

        Text {
            id: someText
            text: Config.someOtherValue
        }
        Text {
            id: anotherText
            text: MainCpp.someValue
        }

        Slider {
            value: 0.5
            maximumValue: 100
            onValueChanged: MainCpp.update(value)
        }
    }
}
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48069595).

Comment: Brilliant as always, thank you very much. I've not used Singletons before, so I'll go through your solution in detail, implement it in my application, and update this post (and mark as answered accordingly).

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks again! I certainly learnt something today :)

Comment: But be careful with singletons! They might make many things easy, but often it might be easy just at the beginning, eventually leading into a mess that is hard to refactor. They might be your friends, but they might just as well be your most fearsome enemy in disguise. You will find much about the pros and even more about the cons of singletons all over the web.

Comment: obviously, one has to be careful, this is a starting point each at the end check if it is what you want, given the information that shows who asks for me was the simplest option, if I had more information could be given other alternatives, thanks for your opinion @derM :P

Comment: @eyllanesc: This was not to critizize you. I think especially in the context of Qt where many things are already singletons and others will not make problems, beeing one, they are a valid solution for some problems. It is just that often people that just discover the singleton tend to abuse it soon, eventually ending up in a mess. Personally I prefer to use *pseudo QML singletons* for publishing C++ models, than using context properties, as it prevents shadowing.

Comment: @derM I could show examples of *pseudo QML singletons*, or some resource where I can see example as questions or post.